# How to Execute SQL Server Stored Procedure in SQL Developer?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've been given a user account to a SQL Server database that only has privileges to execute a stored procedure. I added the JTDS SQL Server JDBC jar file to SQL Developer and added it as a Third Party JDBC driver. I can successfully log in to the SQL Server database.  I was given this syntax for running the procedure:

```
EXEC proc_name 'paramValue1' 'paramValue2'
```

When I run this as either a statement or a script, I get this error:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
EXEC proc_name 'paramValue1' 'paramValue2'
Error report:
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BEGIN'.
```

I tried wrapping the statement in `BEGIN/END`, but get the same error.  Is it possible to call the procedure from SQL Developer?  If so, what syntax do I need to use?

Answer (score 264, accepted):

You don't need EXEC clause. Simply use

```
proc_name paramValue1, paramValue2
```

(and you need commas as Misnomer mentioned)

Comment: EXEC prior proc_name is required in my case

Answer (score 86):

You are  missing `,`

```
EXEC proc_name 'paramValue1','paramValue2'
```

Comment: I added the missing comma, but again, still get the same error.

Comment: What are your parameters if they are varchar then only you need the quotes...other than that can't think of anything...you could try this  just run only this in a new windows- `EXEC proc_name` and see if it asks you for the second parameter...then at least you know your sytax is right..if doesnt work means you probanly dont have right stored proc name...try full qualified name..

Comment: I removed the second paramater and still the same error.  I don't think it's running procedure at all.  The EXEC command isn't syntax highlighted, so I'm guessing Developer doesn't recognize it even though the connection is to a SQL Server database.  But I can't find anything on the web to confirm/deny that.

Comment: Yea..try selecting some records and executing some simple commands see if anything at all works!..best of luck..

Comment: Unfortunately, my user only has privileges to run the stored procedure.

Answer (score 24):

You need to do this:

```
exec procName 
@parameter_1_Name = 'parameter_1_Value', 
@parameter_2_name = 'parameter_2_value',
@parameter_z_name = 'parameter_z_value'
```

Answer (score 5):

```
EXECUTE [or EXEC] procedure_name
@parameter_1_Name = 'parameter_1_Value', 
@parameter_2_name = 'parameter_2_value',
@parameter_z_name = 'parameter_z_value'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `,` between the paramValue1 and paramValue2. You missed it.

```
EXEC proc_name 'paramValue1','paramValue2'
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is the old one. But this may help others.

I have added SP calling function between BEGIN/END. Here is a working script.

```
ALTER Proc [dbo].[DepartmentAddOrEdit]
@Id int,
@Code varchar(100),
@Name varchar(100),
@IsActive bit ,
@LocationId int,
@CreatedBy int,
@UpdatedBy int
AS
    IF(@Id = 0)

    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Department (Code,Name,IsActive,LocationId,CreatedBy,UpdatedBy,CreatedAt)
        VALUES(@Code,@Name,@IsActive,@LocationId,@CreatedBy,@UpdatedBy,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

    EXEC dbo.LogAdd @CreatedBy,'DEPARTMENT',@Name
    END

    ELSE

    UPDATE Department SET
        Code = @Code,
        Name = @Name,
        IsActive = @IsActive,
        LocationId = @LocationId,
        CreatedBy = @CreatedBy,
        UpdatedBy = @UpdatedBy,
        UpdatedAt =  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
    where Id = @Id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EXEC proc_name @paramValue1 = 0, @paramValue2 = 'some text';
GO
```

If the Stored Procedure objective is to perform an `INSERT` on a table that has an Identity field declared, then the field, in this scenario `@paramValue1`, should be declared and just pass the value 0, because it will be auto-increment.

Answer (score 0):

```
--worked for me in sql 5.731
--use db;
call procedureName;
```

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways we can call stored procedure

1. CALL `database name'. 'stored procedure name`(parameter values);
   example:- CALL `dbs_nexopay_sisd1_dec_23`.`spr_v2_invoice_details_for_invoice_receipt_sub_swiss`(1, 1, 1, 1);
2. From your MySQL workbench also you can do that.
   i. Right-click on stored procedure.
   ii. Send to SQL editor
   iii. Procedure call.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

If you simply need to excute your stored procedure 
`proc_name 'paramValue1' , 'paramValue2'...`
at the same time you are executing more than one query like one select query and stored procedure you have to add 
`select * from tableName
EXEC proc_name paramValue1 , paramValue2...`

Answer (score -8):

The stored procedures can be run in sql developer tool using the below syntax

BEGIN
procedurename();
END;

If there are any parameters then it has to be passed.

Comment: Why are you enclosing a single statement by a statement block? You have to do it for a [series of T-SQL statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190487.aspx) only.

Answer (score -11):

```
Select * from Table name ..i.e(are you save table name in sql(TEST) k.

Select * from TEST then you will execute your project.
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Take [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) tour to get to know how this site works and what it is for. What is your answer?