# How to loop through stored procedure result in coldfusion

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion, adobe

I would like to loop the stored procedure in Coldfusion. I have below code to loop through query.

```
<cfquery name="rates" dbtype="query">
        select code, rate
  from application.qry.currency
  where code = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.origCode#" />
     or code = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.toCode#" />
</cfquery>
<cfloop query="rates">
    <cfscript>
            if (code == arguments.origCode) origRate = rate;
            if (code == arguments.toCode) toRate = rate;
        </cfscript>
</cfloop>
```

Now the query is being replaced by the stored procedure as below and I would like to do the same function as above code does for looping. And inside the stored procedure, I do have the same query as above. Thank you in advance!

```
<cfstoredproc procedure="usp_get_rates" datasource="#variables.dsn#">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" dbvarname="@origCode" type="in" value="#arguments.origCode#"/>
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" dbvarname="@toCode" type="in" value="#arguments.toCode#" />
</cfstoredproc>
```

Full code for the above:

```
<cffunction name="convertCurrency" access="public" output="false" returntype="string">
  <cfargument name="amount" required="true" type="numeric" />
<cfargument name="origCode" required="true" type="string" />
<cfargument name="toCode" required="true" type="string" />
<cfscript>
        var theAmount = 0;
        var origRate = 0;
        var toRate = 0;
        var baseVal = 0;
        var newVal = 0;
        if (isNumeric(arguments.amount)) theAmount = arguments.amount;
        if (arguments.origCode == 'USD' && arguments.toCode == 'USD' || theAmount == 0) return theAmount;
        if (not isDefined("application.qry.currency")) initCurrencyRecordset();
    </cfscript>
<cfquery name="rates" dbtype="query">
        select code, rate
  from application.qry.currency
  where code = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.origCode#" />
     or code = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.toCode#" />
</cfquery>
<cfloop query="rates">
    <cfscript>
            if (code == arguments.origCode) origRate = rate;
            if (code == arguments.toCode) toRate = rate;
        </cfscript>
</cfloop>
<cfscript>
        if (origRate neq 0){
            baseVal = theAmount * (1 / origRate);
            newVal  = baseVal * toRate;
        }
        else {
            baseVal = theAmount * 1;
            newVal  = baseVal * toRate;
        }
        return newVal;
    </cfscript>
```

```
  <cffunction name="initCurrencyRecordset" access="private" output="false" returntype="void">
    <!--- <cfquery name="qry" datasource="#variables.dsn#">
        select distinct c.LOCAL_CUR as code, ISNULL(c.LocalConversionToUSD, c.x) as rate
        from SCS_FM.dbo.currency c
        join scs_fm.dbo.currency_code cc
            ON c.local_cur = cc.currency_code
        order by LOCAL_CUR
    </cfquery> --->

    <cfstoredproc procedure="usp_Rates_InitCurrencyRecordset_Qry" datasource="#variables.dsn#">
    <cfprocresult name="qry" >
    </cfstoredproc>

    <cflock scope="application" type="exclusive" timeout="20">
        <cfset application.qry.currency = duplicate(qry) />
    </cflock>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: What if you call store proc from inside cfquery by replacing your sql with it https://stackoverflow.com/a/4136859/3254405

Comment: What is the code you have shared doing? Is it throwing an error? Does it return a record set? What do you get if you dump the result `<cfdump var="#cfstoredproc#">` Please include these details in your question.

Comment: What version of ColdFusion and which DBMS? `dbvarname` was ignored in 6-10, but restored in CF11. But if you're using script inside of a loop, you may as well just put the whole thing in the script and loop inside there.

Comment: @Shawn I am using CF11 and the dbms is sql server 2014. What about the name I should give at this line instead of rates - <cfloop query="rates"> .

Comment: Does the sproc only return one result set? Can you share sample code from the sproc? You can add an "out" `cfprocparam` to your sproc or `<cfprocresult name="rates">` then loop through that result set. I believe the proc result will be the same type of object as a query.

Comment: And what is `application.qry.currency` in your `cfquery`? What that is saying is that you are querying the `application` database, `qry` schema and `currency` table. You also have `dbtype="query"`, which indicates that query is a Query of Query. Is that correct? Is the query above supposed to directly reference a table in the database?

Comment: And lastly, your loop is just overwriting the variable each time it iterates, so you'll ultimately end up with `origRate` and `toRate` being the last `rate` value in the query order (which your query is not currently ordered). Do you have some other code that is doing something within the loop? If you only want one value, then you should just select that single value.

Comment: Actually, I'm going to take one more step back to your query. What is your ultimate goal? Looking at your code, it seems that you are trying to loop through your query to populate a `rate` for both `origRate` and `toRate`, but it may be much easier to do this in the query itself and forego the loop. Can you provide some sample data and an expectation of what you want?

Comment: @shawn I have edited the question above by adding full code. Hope this will make more clear. Thank you.

Comment: So your query will return two or fewer rows for `origCode` and `toCode`? That can probably be shortened to return what you want and not need to loop. Also, is `currency` a query inside `qry` and cached in `application` scope? If so, what are you converting to a stored procedure?

Comment: `if (not isDefined("application.qry.currency")) initCurrencyRecordset();` indicates that you are looking for a query object cached inside the `application` scope. You should probably pass this query object into the query, so that you aren't reaching out of the function to get the query. Also, this does seem to indicate that the query is already done, so you won't be able to convert to a stored procedure unless you go all the way back to the query in `application`. You can't query a CF query from inside a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the details so far, to accomplish what you're asking.....

I'm assuming your stored procedure looks something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_get_rates @origCode varchar(20), @toCode varchar(20)
AS  
BEGIN 
  SET NOCOUNT ON ;
  SELECT code, rate
  FROM dbo.currency
  WHERE code IN ( @origCode, @toCode )
END;  
GO
```

*NOTE: You'd want to replace "dbo" with whatever your appropriate db schema is. But if you are querying across databases (see comment above about `application.qry.currency`), then you'd keep your `FROM` call the same and place/reference your stored procedure in the appropriate schema.*

With that procedure, your ColdFusion code would be like:

```
<cfstoredproc procedure="usp_get_rates" datasource="#variables.dsn#">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" dbvarname="@origCode" type="in" value="#arguments.origCode#">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" dbvarname="@toCode" type="in" value="#arguments.toCode#">
        <cfprocresult name="rates">
</cfstoredproc>

<cfscript>
  // Initialize your variables. They won't exist if your query has 0 rows.
  var origRate = 0 ; // Or expected datatype
  var toRate   = 0 ; // Or expected datatype

  for (var thisrow in rates) {
     if ( thisrow.code == arguments.origCode ) { origRate = thisrow.rate ; }
     if ( thisrow.code == arguments.toCode) { toRate = thisrow.rate ; }
  }
</cfscript>
```

Since you are using `arguments` scope, I'm assuming that this code is inside a function. That would allow you to use the `var` keyword.

Note that `dbvarname` was ignored since CFMX and reinstated in CF11 Update 3. CF11 had a JVM flag ( `-Dcoldfusion.ignoredbvarname` ) to continue to ignore `dbvarname`, but that flag is ignored in CF2016+.

You can use a simple `for` loop to iterate over the query, but as I said above, this may not be what you really want. If your query/sproc returns multiple results, it will overwrite `origRate` or `toRate` if there are more than one value returned for them. ie if your query has `[{code:"x",rate:41},{code:"x",rate:42}]`, it will overwrite `rate` for `code="x"`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will test it and put check on your answer. :)

Comment: @SM  After your latest addition, what does your cached `currency` query look like? Since it's already done, you won't be able to convert a Query of Query to a stored procedure. You'll need the details of the original query also.

Comment: Added the code that is calling another function that is initCurrencyRecordset when application.qry.currency is not defined. @shawn

Comment: @SM I don't know what your database looks like, but it doesn't appear that the cached query is really doing anything with the `JOIN`ed table (`scs_fm.dbo.currency_code`) other than filtering out any records from `SCS_FM.dbo.currency` that don't have a corresponding row. I'll take a look at this more when I get home, but are you able to supply any sample data from your db? I think you can write a new sproc or query that can get what you need in a single call.

Comment: Look at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=57c7ac92a3b0b918f77e662e7198c579 for an idea of how to refactor the query for your sproc.

Comment: And https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=6b60e4ecb318e4b7157c2a6dbe4ff8a5 shows some different data situations.